# maven + elicpse related questions

Tags: maven

Forgive me asking following questions. I am totally lost in regards to maven+eclipse. I checked out someone's java project (maven built) from SVN to my local eclipse (kepler). When I click Windows > Preferences, I see Maven.

question 1) 
Is this a maven plugin? When developers say maven in eclipse, are they referring to maven plugin? maven and maven plugin are two separate components?

question 2) 
when I click on user settings, C:\Users\myName.m2\settings.xml is missing. Exact error message is "User settings file doesn't exist". Does it get created when you install maven plugin at first time?

question 3) 
I found three folders may have to do with maven C:\workspace\maven_local_repo_artifactory directory, C:\maven_local_repo and C:\Users\myName.m2\respository but not sure how they get created and what is the relationship among them.

question 4)
Is it ok to remove current maven plugin from eclipse and re-install it then check out the java project from SVN? I think my maven or maven plugin settings are not correct in my local box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is this a maven plugin? When developers say maven in eclipse, are
>   they referring to maven plugin? maven and maven plugin are two
>   separate components?

Yes. This is the maven-plugin. maven-plugin uses the configurations of maven (%M2_HOME%/conf). 
If you wanna work with maven, you need to install it on your machine. Then you can run maven commmands. In addition, if you want to invoke maven commands within eclipse (conveniently) - you can install the eclipse-plugin. "maven-plugin" is a plugin for eclipse, that lets you use maven within Eclipse conveniently.

> 2) when I click on user settings, C:\Users\myName.m2\settings.xml is
>   missing. Exact error message is "User settings file doesn't exist".
>   Does it get created when you install maven plugin at first time?

By default, the maven-plugin assumes that your settings.xml (which is the configuration file of maven) is in the path you have mentioned. However, there are cases (like in my case) where the config file is not there, but under %M2_HOME%/conf. you can update it in Eclipse, and the error will disappear.

> 3) I found three folders may have to do with maven
>   C:\workspace\maven_local_repo_artifactory directory,
>   C:\maven_local_repo and C:\Users\myName.m2\respository but not sure
>   how they get created and what is the relationship among them.

C:\Users\myName.m2\respository is the "local repository". If you learned a bit about how maven works, it holds a local repo on the local machine, and it keeps there all artifacts. It downloads them from the "repository" - if you have one in your company ([Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books/repository-management-with-nexus), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/), etc) or from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/). However, this path is configurable by Maven's settings. So there might be that someone played with it and changed the path, and these other directories were created. You did not mention what resides inside these paths...

> 4) Is it ok to remove current maven plugin from eclipse and re-install
>   it then check out the java project from SVN? I think my maven or maven
>   plugin settings are not correct in my local box.

Sure it is OK. You may remove the plugin, and the source plus maven itself will not be deleted from your machine.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. I see that maven does not need to be installed on my local box, but in order to interact with a project built in maven in eclipse conveniently as you said I need a plugin (no need to run command lines I assume). Did I understand it correctly? All the directory paths I mentioned contain artifacts (external API in jar files the project refer to). I wasn't sure which one maven was using it though.

Comment: I will re-install plugin in and then check out the project. Before hand I will delete aforementioned folders. Would it ok though? After re-installing the plugin I believe /users/myName/.m2 directory will be created. Please correct me if I am wrong on this. Have a blessed day!

Comment: well - if you wanna work with maven, you need to install it on your machine. then, you can run maven commmands. in addition, if you want to invoke maven commands within eclipse (conveniently) - you can install the eclipse-plugin.

Comment: your answer helped me. m2 comes with maven that i don't have to install separately as you pointed out. thank you again! I just marked it as "accepted".